# Why "sshd Bad prime description" errors?

Tags: freebsd, sshd

I've noticed that all our FreeBSD machines throw sshd Bad prime description in line xxx (insert a large number of values for xxx).

Presumably this is not something they are all supposed to be doing (despite the fact that there's no visible problems with functionality).  Unfortunately, I've not been able to find any useful resources on the web that relate to this problem.

Any pointers for troubleshooting/making this obnoxious message go away?

Comment: Where/when does this message show up? Are you looking at some log file?

Comment: Shows up on the console periodically (at user login, and then occasionally while in active use).  Also shows up in the syslog.

Comment: It looks like a security warning. ssh uses large prime numbers, the larger the better. It looks like it is warning that they are to small. Can you give more context, where you see this error. So someone can help.

Comment: There's not really any more context to give.  It's a FreeBSD 9.2 box, upgraded from 9.0 awhile back (possibly up from 8.3 before that).  Message appears when people login via SSH, and periodically while people are logged in (I presume it resets it's key occasionally?).  Everything (other than the error) appears to work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was incorrect in saying it was all of our machines.  It did afflict multiples, but eventually I found one without the problem!  I copied the /etc/ssh/moduli file from that machine and put it onto the others and the problem is solved!